# Dynamically Allocating Struct

Tags: c++, struct

I have five different structs that may be created depending on a the "type" variable. I have many lines of code that rely on this "temp" object to be present (There's about 50 lines of code that load variables into the struct).

Currently, the code listed below doesn't work, as temp is confined to the local scope of the if statement, so it doesn't exist outside of it.

I can't simply instantiate a generic port at the top, because each of these ports have different characteristics.

Obviously I could just include all of the member assignment code into the if statement, but that's incredibly messy and unelegent.

Is there a way to assign the proper variables to each port type without having to massively restructure my code?

```
std::string id;
std::string type;
std::string converter;

inputStream >> id;
inputStream >> type;

if(type == "FC") {
    portFc temp;
}
else if(type == "SAS") {
    portSas temp;
}
else if(type == "PCIe") {
    portPcie temp;
}
else if(type == "iSCSI") {
    portIscsi temp;
}
else if(type == "IPREP") {
    portIprep temp;
}
else {
    portGeneric temp;
}

inputStream >> temp.foo;
inputStream >> temp.bar;
inputStream >> temp.bash;
.
.
.
inputStream >> temp.final;
```

Comment: *Is there a way to assign the proper variables to each port type without having to massively restructure my code?*  No.

Comment: This is what unions are for.  Can you not make a union of all five port types?  Then you need only one variable at the top and you fill in the union member based on the temp variable?  If that would work for you I could write an answer with sample code?

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is a safer alternative to a `union` for cases like these. But maybe polymorphism is a better approach here.

Comment: I could make these ports a class, but it would require a massive restructuring of the entire system I am using. In short, the "port" is just one kind of data I am collecting. The rest of the data uses structs just fine, but these ports are a special case. So, using some nice C++ polymorphism isn't really an option here (unless I want to do a massive amount of work).

Comment: Structs are classes. (Also, 50 lines of code is not much.)

Comment: You could have a parent struct 'Type' and derive individual structs for each type of port. However, the way you have declared 'temp' won't work; it will have to be declared outside the if-else block. Then assign temp to the derived struct.

Comment: There's something odd about this question. What can you do with `temp` later, given that you don't know what type it is? Can you show us why you need `temp` to have different types even though all the code you've shown does exactly the same thing regardless of type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There'd be a relatively simple way to do this using generic lambdas, introduced in C++14. The way the function works is almost identical to the way you had it, except we need to define the lambda containing the rest of the function *before* the series of `if` statements (since it needs to be present in scope when you call it).

```
void doStuff(std::istream& inputStream) {
    std::string id;
    std::string type;
    std::string converter;

    inputStream >> id;
    inputStream >> type;

    // Create a generic lambda that contains the rest of the stuff 
    // you need to do 
    auto stuffToDo = [&](auto temp) {
        inputStream >> temp.foo;
        inputStream >> temp.bar;
        inputStream >> temp.bash;
        // ....
        inputStream >> temp.final;
    };

    if(type == "FC") {
        stuffToDo(portFc{});
    }
    else if(type == "SAS") {
        stuffToDo(portSas{});
    }
    else if(type == "PCIe") {
        stuffToDo(portPcie{});
    }
    else if(type == "iSCSI") {
        stuffToDo(portIscsi{});
    }
    else if(type == "IPREP") {
        stuffToDo(portIprep{});
    }
    else {
        stuffToDo(portGeneric{});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal thing to do would be to have a shared base class:

```
struct portCommon {
    std::string foo;
    std::string bar;
    std::string bash.
};
struct portFc : public portCommon {
};
...etc
```

and a map of factories.

```
const std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<portCommon>>> factories = {
    {"FC", [](){return std::make_unique<portFc>();}},
    {"SAS", [](){return std::make_unique<portSas>();}},
    {"PCIe", [](){return std::make_unique<portPcie>();}},
    {"iSCSI", [](){return std::make_unique<portIscsi>();}},
    {"IPREP", [](){return std::make_unique<portIprep>();}}
};
```

With a helper method:

```
std::unique_ptr<portCommon> createPort(const std::string& type) {
    auto iter = factories.find(type);
    if (iter != factories.end()) {
        return iter->second();
    } else {
        return std::make_unique<portGeneric>();
    }
}
```

Then the code is simpler:

```
std::string id;
std::string type;

inputStream >> id;
inputStream >> type;

std::unique_ptr<portCommon> temp = createPort(type);
inputStream >> temp->foo;
inputStream >> temp->bar;
inputStream >> temp->bash;
.
.
.
inputStream >> temp->final;
```